# GCP free trial billing account creation stuck

Tags: google-cloud-platform

since an hour or so I'm stuck in creating a GCP billing account.

I can go all way (providing phone number, address, credit card info) >> do the credit card security check. But right after I confirm the security code for my credit card the regarding popup closes and I'm stuck on the tab "Step 2 of 2 - Free Trial - Google Cloud Platform" with a turning wheel indicating that something is processed ...

Tried several times in Chrome and Safari. Updated my Credit Card App (DKB).

Any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: Hi there! Not the best place to look for support. Contact Google Cloud Billing support (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) They will be able to address all your concerns.

Comment: I found another menu that instead of hanging presented a quota error (at approx 5 projects). If this is you, try https://support.google.com/code/contact/billing_quota_increase

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, try doing the process again with a separate browser, I got through to step 3 and successfully created the account within minutes. I initially used Google, but then retried with Microsoft Edge and it worked. Hope this  helps.

Comment: same for me.. failed repeatedly in firefox then worked first time in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

reaching out to the billing team by filing a billing support request at [1] will be the best place to ask for assistance for your situation.

[1] https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Answer (score 0):

Its browser issue, I used brave browser with shield & without shield nothing worked.
Then I tried Opera and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the problem turned out to be that the billing account I was attempting to link was already linked to 3 other projects.
By creating a new billing account or requesting a project limit increase fixes the issue.